# Solving recurrence with vectors

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

I am trying to learn more about how to model questions about recurrence relations using matrices. How would one approach the following problem:

"Suppose $y_n$ and $x_n$ satisfy:

$\begin{bmatrix}x_{n}\\y_{n}\end{bmatrix}$
= $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}x_{n-1}\\y_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$

with $x_0 = y_0 = 1$. What is $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ assuming this limit exists?"

I am not used to seeing a recurrence expressed in this way. The author mentions a "standard trick," which I am also unaware of.

Comment: If $A$ stands for the matrix on the right then, by iterating, you get that  $\begin{bmatrix}x_{n}\\y_{n}\end{bmatrix} = A^n \begin{bmatrix}x_{0}\\y_{0}\end{bmatrix}$ So, if $B$ is Jordan's form of $A$  then $A^n = CB^nC^{-1}$. But $B^n$ has a simple form ...

Answer (score 2):

As $A = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = T\cdot\Lambda\cdot T^{-1}$ with $T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right) \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\Lambda =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{5}\right) & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$ we have

$$
X_n = T\cdot\Lambda\cdot T^{-1}X_{n-1}
$$

or

$$
T^{-1}X_{n} = \Lambda\cdot T^{-1}X_{n-1}
$$

now calling $Y_n = T^{-1}X_{n}$ we follow with

$$
Y_n = \Lambda Y_{n-1}
$$

with solution

$$
Y_n = \Lambda^n\cdot Y_0
$$

hence

$$
X_n = T\cdot\Lambda^n\cdot T^{-1}X_0
$$

Here $\Lambda^n = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n & 0 \\
 0 & \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that in this specific case
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^2,$$
so that the solution can be expressed in terms of the Fibonacci sequence (with $F_{-1},F_0,F_1,F_2=1,0,1,1$).
One can test that the sequence
$$
z_0=y_0,~~z_1=x_0,~~~z_{n+2}=z_{n+1}+z_n\\
\implies z_n=x_0F_n+y_0F_{n-1}
$$
gives the solution of the original task as
$$
x_n=z_{2n+1}~\text{ and }~ y_n=z_{2n}
$$

This gives the ratio as
$$
\frac{x_n}{y_n}=\frac{x_0F_{2n+1}+y_0F_{2n}}{x_0F_{2n}+y_0F_{2n-1}}
\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}
\frac{x_0\phi+y_0}{x_0+y_0(\phi-1)}
$$